# Axis2 keeps generating files in temp folder when running on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, apache-axis, axis

When deploying a web application on tomcat which uses Axis2 for SOAP communication, then in the tomcat temp directory '**apache-tomcat-6.0.29\temp**' we keep getting a folder such as 'axis2-tmp-21936.tmp' holding jars for the deployed **Axis2** modules such as **Rampart** (for e.g. axis21098rampart-mar-1.5.1.jar).

The files keep growing until they fill up your hard drive.

I have attempted using the same **context** and **stub** for the subsequent calls, but that doesn't fix the issue.

It turns out this is a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3919)  in Axis2, fixed in version 1.7, which is not yet released and may not even fix it according to some people.

Note, when deploying on eclipse, these files go to C:\users\User\appdata\local\temp\; also, on standalone non-web applications, the files get generated only once and get deleted on restart.

The issue turned out to be invalid as the context was always being re-created - details in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a class being constantly re-created which is initializing a new Context on each service call.

In a nutshell:

- The Axis2 (temp files) issue does not reproduce on Axis2 1.5.4.
- Temp fles are generated only on the creation of a new Axis2 Context.
- Temp files are NOT generated when a new stub class is created.